# Date range using period_name

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table `gl_balances` which has the column `period_name` which the date `mmm-yy` but in string format.

I need to pull the data from `gl_balances` between a certain period so all the data between `:period_name_from` and `:period_name_to`.

Im struggling to figure out how to do this.

There is the table `gl_periods` which has `period_name`, `period_year` and `period_num` (*month number*) which are probably helpful too

Im expecting to to show all the data from `gl_balances` table between two `period_name` periods.

Ive tried lots of things but I think Ive made a mess of it!

Comment: Hi is it possible for you to give us some sample data and the table structure, you can use the TO_DATE function  to convert string to date and use BETWEEN function to get the data. https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/between.php

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this. select to_date('OCT-23','MON-YY') from dual . Should be a good starting point along with the BETWEEN function. Beware if you need the boundaries to behave in a particular way that BETWEEN is inclusive.

Comment: It's a bit strange that you have a period table, but it doesn't contain the period's start and end date. You may want to change your data model. What does mmm in mmm-yy mean by the way? A three-letter month abbreviation? If so, which language?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a table gl_balances which has the column `period_name` which the date `mmm-yy` but in string format.
>
> I need to pull the data from `gl_balances` between a certain period so all the data between `:period_name_from` and `:period_name_to`.

Assuming that your bind variables are also strings in the format `JAN-23` then convert the strings to dates and use `BETWEEN`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   gl_balances
WHERE  TO_DATE(period_name, 'MON-RR') BETWEEN TO_DATE(:period_name_from, 'MON-RR')
                                          AND TO_DATE(:period_name_to, 'MON-RR');
```

If your bind variable are dates then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   gl_balances
WHERE  TO_DATE(period_name, 'MON-RR') BETWEEN :period_name_from
                                          AND :period_name_to;
```

or, if you want entire months when the `period_name_from` bind variables partially overlaps (note: the end month will never overlap as `TO_DATE(period_name, 'MON-RR')` will be midnight of the first day of the month):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   gl_balances
WHERE  TO_DATE(period_name, 'MON-RR') BETWEEN TRUNC(:period_name_from, 'MM')
                                          AND :period_name_to;
```